# Instead of implicitly typing (var), how do I explicitly type static variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, implicit, explicit

Currently I implicitly typed *eventOperation*:

`var eventOperation = EventOperations.Cancel;`

But I explicitly type *eventOperation* so that I don't have to assign an arbitrary value before an if statement. Plus, I can't initialize variables within the if statement or have an uninitialized implicit typed variable.

Here's my definition of the static class:

```
public static class EventOperations
{
    ...
    public static OperationAuthorizationRequirement Cancel =
      new OperationAuthorizationRequirement { Name = Constants.CancelOperationName };
}

public class Constants
{
    ...
    public static readonly string CancelOperationName = "Cancel";
    ...
}
```

Comment: `But I explicitly type eventOperation so that I don't have to assign an arbitrary value before an if statement.` Please show an example of an if statement that you are trying to build.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what your problem is. Please specify.

Comment: I'm not sure to get the question, but var is only made that type declaration is automatic regarding the type of data you're assigning. I guess... just use Visual Studio tools to figure out which kind of data you're using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EventOperations.Cancel` obviously is of type `OperationAuthorizationRequirement`. So simply declare your variable as

```
OperationAuthorizationRequirement eventOperation = EventOperations.Cancel;
```

Comment: This works. Its just that I misspelled it and it was giving me a namespace error without giving me a proper fix so I thought its something else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be:

```
var eventOperation = null as EventOperations;
```

This way you can still declare your variable using var (implicitly) but specify the data type on the right, so the compiler can figure it out.

## UPDATE

Your original post implies `static` variable declaration. I'm not sure if you using the term correctly here, but if you do, the situation slightly change...

As C# doesn't support static local variables, you need to declare the variable as `static` on a module level, i.e. not within a method but directly in the class.

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    private static EventOperations eventOperation = null;
    
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        if(true)
        {
            eventOperation = EventOperations.Cancel; // whatever value you set here, it'll be propagated to all the instances of some class.
        }
    }
}
```